# C# SQLite, get real type?

Tags: c#, sqlite, compact-framework

how we get the type `real` column from the Sqlite?! I'm using the CF 3.5 for windows CE and the `SQLite.Interop.066.DLL` for the SQLite requirements

I have tryed Float, Decimal and such but nothing works, since according to several sites that I have found they say that real is used for float and other types that as a decimal

Comment: Tried to do: `GetType()` on your cell? I never did SQLite, but when i get a datatable, i perform `GetType()` on the cell-values, to see what my ODP.Net does..

Comment: Will try thanks for the tip

Comment: I' getting Int32 on the GetType() doing it like this: `reader.GetOrdinal("pr_publico").GetType()` and I'm 1000% sure that the column is real -.-

Comment: SQLite works a bit different, they don't seem to enforce the column type on values. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Then how I would get it? Could I get a example? BtW if I check the `_fieldArrayType` is saying that is Single, but the `SQLiteDataReader` doesn't have a GetSingle, `SQLDataReader` does have :/

Comment: But is the Column is real and the value that I'm trying to get its 0.31 its not a Int32, and I'm using this on a part of the code `(float)readerLite.GetDouble(readerLite.GetOrdinal("columnValue"))` and its geting the value without any problem :/

Comment: You need to look up the docos on `GetOrdinal`, as i don't think it is what you are looking for.  To quote Inigo Montoya, "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." :)  The ordinal is just a field number, as in 1st col, 2nd col, etc.  `reader.GetOrdinal("pr_publico").GetType()` will always be a Int